# how does the software firewall affect the hardware network card?

Tags: port, windows-firewall, wake-on-lan

I am waking my computer up by sending magic packets. But if I close UDP port 9 from windows firewall, my computers is not booting. And also, the lights on ethernet port are off.

It looks little too strange to me. Afaik, the software firewall, windows or any operating system should be off if computer is powered off.

Any ideas? How software firewall effects the network card while it is not running?

Comment: That makes no sense at all. The windows firewall does nothing when the computer is off.  You have very obviously misdiagnosed your computer! Try a few more times allowing and blocking UDP port 9, and see if the lights on the ethernet socket change.. If you were right this shouldn't even affect the lights on the port even when the computer is on. Maybe even make a video of it! (if you blocked absolutely everything then i'd be surprised if it had an effect.. 'cos there's still packets coming in.. but you're not even doing that, you're just blocking udp port 9..

Comment: And by the way, even if you block everything in the windows firewall, some stuff still goes through, as you'd see if you loaded up wireshark. ARP but some UDP and even some TCP stuff.

Comment: Actually NVidia released a chipset with hardware firewall a while ago - google nForce 4. And it could be set up from software. So - not so infeasible as one might think.

Comment: @DarkWanderer  I mean the windows firewall (His tag said windows firewall) can't do it(win7 i tested it). no doubt the xp firewall can't(though WIPFW can probably do all ip e.g. also all tcp and udp,  it doesn't seem to have an arp option), and while I can get wipfw installed in xp, I can't get wipfw to install on win7 and it seems to lack support. Interesting re nForce 4.